# Store Array in array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I would like to display availabilities of a company grouped by date. I have these data:
[image: entity "Disponibilite"]

**Here an example of I want to display** :
[image]

**Here What I have** : 
[image]

Here my code. I explained it step by step in comments. 
For resume it : for every availability, I check if the day is already in my list of days (who contains availabilities). 
If I don't find it, I add the day if my list of days & I add an array. In the same time I add in this same array the hour of my current availability.

If I found it, I only add the hour in the sub array (index : 0).

Is there a better way to group my "hours" per day ?

```
foreach($entreprises as $entreprise)
                {
                    // Array of days
                    $Disponibilites = array();
                  //  Array of day who contains availabilities. 
                    $JourneesDisponibles=array('nomJourDispo'=>'test1','jourDispo'=>'test2','moisDispo'=>'test3','jourMoisDispo'=>'test4');
                    $j=0;
                            foreach($entreprise[0]->getPropose() as $dispos)
                            {
                                // For each availability, I store its time, day and month
                                $jourDispo = new \DateTime();

                                $dateDispo = $dispos->getDateDispo(); // The whole date : YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
                                $nomJourDispo = $dispos->getJourDispo(); //  Day , ex : Lundi (monday)
                                $jourDispo = $dateDispo->format('d'); // Day, ex : 22
                                $moisDispo = $dispos->getMoisDispo(); // month
                                $heureDispo = $dateDispo->format('H:i'); //Hour
                                $jourMoisDispo = $jourDispo.$moisDispo; //Day + Month = unique in the year

                               // if(($JourneesDisponibles['jourMoisDispo']) != null)
                               for($j = 0; $j < count($JourneesDisponibles);++$j)
                               {
                                  // Here I'm looking for the day - If it not exists, I add it in the list of days. 
                                   if($JourneesDisponibles['jourMoisDispo'] != $jourMoisDispo){
                                    $JourneesDisponibles['nomJourDispo']=$nomJourDispo;
                                    $JourneesDisponibles['jourDispo']=$jourDispo;
                                    $JourneesDisponibles['moisDispo']=$moisDispo;
                                    $JourneesDisponibles['jourMoisDispo']=$jourMoisDispo;
                                    // Here I add an array to the array (index : 0) who contains the hour of the availability
                                    array_push($JourneesDisponibles,array($heureDispo)); 

                                   }
                                  else
                                  {
                                    // Else, If the day already exists, I add the hour of the availability in the day.
                                      array_push($JourneesDisponibles[0],($heureDispo));
                                  }

                               }

                                //Here I add the day of availabilities in the list of availabilities
                                array_push($Disponibilites,$JourneesDisponibles); 
                            } 
                        // Here I associate the company with its availabilities     
                        array_push($entreprises[$i],$Disponibilites); 
                        $i++;
                }

    // I return all objects I need 
      return $this->render('CalandmeBundle:Default:recherche.html.twig',array('adresse' => $adresse,'latitude'=>$latitude,
      'longitude'=>$longitude,'entreprises'=>$entreprises));
```

I tried this but I get an undefined offset error (0) :

```
                       for($j = 0; $j < count($JourneesDisponibles);++$j)
                       {
                          // Here I'm looking for the day - If it not exists, I add it in the list of 
                           if($JourneesDisponibles[$j]['jourMoisDispo'] != $jourMoisDispo){
                            $JourneesDisponibles[$j]['nomJourDispo']=$nomJourDispo;
                            $JourneesDisponibles[$j]['jourDispo']=$jourDispo;
                            $JourneesDisponibles[$j]['moisDispo']=$moisDispo;
                            $JourneesDisponibles[$j]['jourMoisDispo']=$jourMoisDispo;
                            // Here I add an array to the array (index : 0) who contains the hour of the availability
                            array_push($JourneesDisponibles[$j],array($heureDispo)); 

                           }
                          else
                          {
                            // Else, If the day is recognized, I add the hour of the availability in the day.
                              array_push($JourneesDisponibles[$j][0],($heureDispo));
                          }
                           array_push($Disponibilites,$JourneesDisponibles[$j]); 
                       }
```

***EDIT : I add a new array but the condition doesn't work***

```
foreach($entreprises as $entreprise)
                {
                    // Array of availabilities
                    $Disponibilites = array();
                  //  Array of day who contains availabilities. 
                    $JourneesDisponibles=array(array('nomJourDispo'=>'','jourDispo'=>'','moisDispo'=>'','jourMoisDispo'=>''));
                  //  $Journee= array();
                    $j=0;
                            foreach($entreprise[0]->getPropose() as $dispos)
                            {
                                // For each availability, I store its time, day and month
                                $jourDispo = new \DateTime();

                                $dateDispo = $dispos->getDateDispo(); // The whole date : YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
                                $nomJourDispo = $dispos->getJourDispo(); //  Day , ex : Lundi (monday)
                                $jourDispo = $dateDispo->format('d'); // Day, ex : 22
                                $moisDispo = $dispos->getMoisDispo(); // month
                                $heureDispo = $dateDispo->format('H:i'); //Hour
                                $jourMoisDispo = $jourDispo.$moisDispo; //Day + Month = unique in the year

                               // if(($JourneesDisponibles['jourMoisDispo']) != null)
                               for($j = 0; $j < count($JourneesDisponibles);++$j)
                               {
                                  // Here I'm looking for the day - If it not exists, I add it in the list of 
                                 // $key=0;

                                 //  var_dump(($JourneesDisponibles));
                                   if($JourneesDisponibles[$j]['nomJourDispo'] != $jourMoisDispo){
                                    $JourneesDisponibles[$j]['nomJourDispo']=$nomJourDispo;
                                    $JourneesDisponibles[$j]['jourDispo']=$jourDispo;
                                    $JourneesDisponibles[$j]['moisDispo']=$moisDispo;
                                    $JourneesDisponibles[$j]['jourMoisDispo']=$jourMoisDispo;
                                    // Here I add an array to the array (index : 0) who contains the hour of the availability
                                    array_push($JourneesDisponibles[$j],array($heureDispo)); 

                                   }
                                  else
                                  {
                                    // Else, If the day is recognized, I add the hour of the availability in the day.
                                      array_push($JourneesDisponibles[$j][0],($heureDispo));
                                  }
                                   array_push($Disponibilites,$JourneesDisponibles[$j]); 
                               }

                                //Here I add the day of availabilities in the list of availabilities

                            } 
                        // Here I associate the company with its availabilities     
                        array_push($entreprises[$i],$Disponibilites); 
                        $i++;
                }
```

I get this, How can I fix the condition ?

[image]

Comment: This might be a better question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @devlincarnate CR is for improving the design of working code, not fixing bugs.

Comment: @Barmar - at the time I made that comment, there was no indication of error.  The question was about a better approach.

Comment: If `$JourneesDisponibles[$j]` is an associative array, `array_push($JourneesDisponibles[$j], ...)` doesn't make much sense. That's for numeric arrays.

Comment: You are right. For use this condition, I think I have to do an other array who contains an array of my day who contains an array with hours...

Comment: What do you mean by a better way to group my 'hours' per day?

Comment: I think my idea can't works if I use an associative array. I tried a lot of thing but I don't get what I want

Answer (score 0):

Given your first column data only, you can chunk the array by date (converting dates to timestamps), and then iterate through them and display those timestamps as you wish.  Here with a simple display example:

```
<?php
$availabilities = 
    array (
        '18-01-04 09:00:00',
        '18-01-04 10:00:00',
        '18-01-04 11:00:00',
        '18-01-05 12:00:00',
        '18-01-05 13:00:00',
    );

$chunked_by_day = [];
foreach($availabilities as $availability)
    $chunked_by_day[date('Ymd', $ts = strtotime($availability))][] = $ts;

foreach($chunked_by_day as $day)
    echo
        date('D d M', $day[0])
    ,
        "\n"
    ,
        implode(' ', array_map(function($v) {
            return date('H:i', $v);
        }, $day))
    ,
        "\n";
```

Output:

```
Thu 04 Jan
09:00 10:00 11:00
Fri 05 Jan
12:00 13:00
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your help. It's a nice idea but I have to do the output in Twig. At the end of my code You can see I associate the list of days with the 'Entreprise' Object : `array_push($entreprises[$i],$Disponibilites);`

After I can return the whole object 'entreprises'
`return $this->render('CalandmeBundle:Default:recherche.html.twig',array('adresse' => $adresse,'latitude'=>$latitude,
      'longitude'=>$longitude,'entreprises'=>$entreprises));`